# Clear Safari data on iOS with ease

Tags: ios, safari, privacy

Clearing data of Safari on iOS need settings-scroll to safari-click-scroll to clear data button-click-click failed because it is still scrolling-click-confirm.

Can there be an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear history data, you can do so directly in Safari.

Blocking All Cookies in Safari settings automatically clears all website data. I don't believe turning it on prevents new website data from storing, however.

Comment: The need is to delete cookie on exit like Chrome. Many sites can't work without cookie.

Comment: Maybe use Private Browsing?

Comment: That's to remove browsing history. The need is to delete cookie.

Comment: @iUnknown Safari Private Browsing only stores cookies for that session then deletes them on window close

Comment: is that true? Then thats the answer.

Comment: Yes. It only stores cookies within the individual tab. Try using https://www.whatarecookies.com/cookietest.asp to test.